# Geometry Construction AAS

Tags: geometry

I want to construct triangle $ABC$ given an angle $x = \angle CAB$, and an angle $y = \angle ABC$ and side $BC$.

This doesn't seem too tricky I know BC and am given angles x and y. However I think I need to utilize the Thales Locus? As this question I am to pick steps necessary for the construction.

a. Construct the Thales' locus for angle y on BC

b. Make C(B,AB)

c. Copy angle y to B along BC

d. Construct the Thales' locus for angle x on BC.

I am sure I need to do part c and copy the angle onto BC. Also part B is not possible because I am not given AB, so I cannot construct that circle.

However I am not sure I should construct thales locus for angle y or x?

Comment: Did you want to write $x = \angle CAB$? Here's how: `$x = \angle CAB$`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the exterior angle at $C$ is equal to the sum of the angles at $A$ and $B$. So you draw $BC$, draw the ray at $B$ at the required angle, and draw the other ray at $C$ at an angle of $(180^\circ-B-A)$. This gives you the triangle.

Comment: Yea that's how I would solve it. It's fairly easy to see how to construct the triangle. But for this problem I have to actually decide what steps are necessary to construct the triangle. And I am not sure if I should be utilizing a or d for this?

Comment: If you want to construct Thales' locus you have you do it for the angle $x$.

Comment: I see. But if I were to construct thales locus with angle x, I am not questioning whether I even need to Copy angle y to B along BC. As wouldn't constructing the thales locus with x simply yield the steps necessary to construct triangle ABC?